# Arduino initiation of a class containing an array of a class

Tags: arrays, class, arduino

hi so im making a hierarchy sort of structure for a robotic walker to make the number of servos manageable and im trying to create a Limb class that contains a number of servo classes (yes im using the built in servo Library but i want to also tweak the offset,scale ect. of the value for calibration purposes) anyway hear is my code.

the problem is the Limb Class initiator (bottom 4 lines) i usually dont like just straight up asking for the correct line of code and prefer to figure it out but iv tried everything i can think of

PS i apolagise for any crap spelling and thanks

```
class ServoConfig{
  public :
  float Offset;
  float Scale;
  bool Inversed;

  Servo ServoV;

  ServoConfig (float InOffset, float InScale, bool InInversed,int Pin){
      float Offset = InOffset;
      float Scale = InScale;
      bool Inversed = InInversed;
      ServoV.attach(Pin);
  }

  void WriteToServo(float Angle){
    if (Inversed){
      ServoV.write((180-Angle)/Scale + Offset);
    }
    else{
      ServoV.write(Angle/Scale + Offset);
    }  
  }
};

class Limb{

  ServoConfig Servos[];

  Limb (ServoConfig InServos[]){
    ServoConfig Servos[] = InServos;
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not so easy in C++ and on Arduino it's even harder.

But first you have loads of mistakes in code. For example shadowing class attibutes by local variables:

```
ServoConfig (float InOffset, float InScale, bool InInversed,int Pin) {
  float Offset = InOffset;    // this will create new local variable and hides that one in class with the same name
  float Scale = InScale;      // this too
  bool Inversed = InInversed; // and this too
```

The same is in Limb constructor, but it doesn't work anyways.

And how it can be working? You can use something like this:

```
#include <Servo.h>

class ServoConfig {
  public :
    float Offset;
    float Scale;
    bool Inversed;

    Servo ServoV;

    ServoConfig (float InOffset, float InScale, bool InInversed,int Pin)
      : Offset   { InOffset   }
      , Scale    { InScale    }
      , Inversed { InInversed }
    {
      ServoV.attach(Pin); // it might have to be attached in setup() as constructors are called before main()
    }

    void WriteToServo(float Angle){
      if (Inversed) {
        ServoV.write((180-Angle)/Scale + Offset);
      } else {
        ServoV.write(Angle/Scale + Offset);
      }  
    }
};

ServoConfig servos[] = {{10,10,0,9},{0,1,0,10}}; // this makes servos of size two and calls constructors

class Limb {
  public:
    ServoConfig * servos_begin;
    ServoConfig * servos_end;

    Limb(ServoConfig * beg, ServoConfig * end)
      : servos_begin { beg }
      , servos_end   { end }
    {;}

    ServoConfig * begin() { return servos_begin;              }
    ServoConfig *   end() { return servos_end;                }
    size_t         size() { return servos_end - servos_begin; }
};

// much better than using  sizeof(array)/sizeof(array[0]):
template <class T, size_t size> size_t arraySize(T(&)[size]) { return size; }

// create and construct Limb instance:
Limb limb { servos, servos + arraySize(servos)};



void setup(){
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop(){
  Serial.println("starting...");

  for (ServoConfig & servo : limb) { // this uses begin() and end() methods
    servo.WriteToServo(90);
  }

  // or directly with array[]
  for (ServoConfig & servo : servos) {
    servo.WriteToServo(40);
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks man you have put me to shame. spent all day trying to figure this out and still turned up nothing. although in fairness a lot of the stuff i came across today explains what you have done and i wouldn't have known otherwise